# How to get GUID of current workspace

Tags: plasticscm

`cm status` gives me the changeset number of the workspace (e.g. `cs:5178`).  Is there any way for me to retrieve the associated GUID, from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following command:

```
cm find changeset where changesetid=123 --format={guid} --nototal
```